# If all eigenvalues of a matrix are 0 or 1, does that imply the matrix is idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf X$ be a square matrix whose only eigenvalues are $\lambda \in \{0, 1\}$. Does that imply that ${\mathbf X}^2 = {\mathbf X}$?

I see that there must exist a vector $v\neq {\bf 0}$ such that ${\mathbf X} v = \lambda v$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then ${\mathbf X }v = 0$. But how do I get the desired conclusion in this case?

If $\lambda = 1$, then ${\mathbf X} v = v$, in which case ${\mathbf X}^2v = {\mathbf X}v$ and $v^2 = v{\mathbf X}^2v$, etc.. But I have not found any method of proving the desired rule here, as well.

Comment: I'm confused. Can it be any eigenvalue which is $0$ or $1$, but the rest may vary? Must they all be $0$ or $1$ exclusively? To either, the matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x \\ 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are obvious counterexamples for $x \ne 0$, as matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ or a subring thereof. If $1$ and $0$ must be used at some point in the eigenvalues but no restrictions are otherwise made on the dimension, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & x \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are counterexamples for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Clearly, if this problem is to be formulated in a meaningful way where with a positive answer, there are conditions that are either being left out or poorly communicated.

Comment: If a matrix is idempotent then it is diagonalizable, as it's minimal polynomial splits. That's why @PrincessEev is giving you *non diagonalizable* counterexamples: there are many matrices whose eigenvalues are only 0 or 1 but which are not diagonalizable!

Comment: That's actually not why I was giving those examples *(though I suppose this is a matter of perspective)*, it was just my first instinct to try a few examples with what felt like a bold claim: matrices with enough well-placed zeroes tend to vanish when raising them to powers. Nice to know that though lol.

Comment: @JeanMarie You're correct, thanks for the catch

Comment: @PrincessEev Thanks for the explanation, which I found more instructive than the actual examples.

Comment: What role does the word "strictly" play in statement? There is no such as thing as being a "non-strict" element of $\{0,1\}$...  is the intent to say that *all* eigenvalues lie in $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$ gives us $\lambda^2 = 0$, i.e., $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ (with multiplicity two.) However,
$$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ne A$$

---

**Edit:** We can find counterexamples even when all the eigenvalues are $1$. Take
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then, $$B^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \ne B$$